# What is the maximum limit of records to be updated in oracle database using Azure function?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-logic-apps, azure-function-app

There is a requirement for the initial load of almost 500k customers into the oracle database. We are planning to achieve this using Azure function.

Is that possible? if not, can you suggest any alternative approaches.

Please note that connecting to client's database can only be possible using VNET as it is hosted in a private network.

Comment: Where is your data coming from? I don't really see how azure function is related to an initial database load at all.

Comment: i would highly recommend data factory when you are doing long-running data operations. i'm happy to assist further

Comment: @JamesZ - We are getting the data from sftp file systems in form of csv files, it may have 5 lakhs to 7 lakhs records. We are thinking of azure function because we are also dealing with incremental data uploads right after initial load, so, in order to avoid duplicate work, we wanted to go with single approach for both the data.

Comment: @AlexGordon - Thanks Alex for the suggestion, we have initial load volume data of about (5 lakhs to 7 lakhs) and incremental load (2k to 5k Daily). Can you please suggest us we can use the same AD solution for both initial and incremental load.? How expensive it is when compared with Azure functions? Logic apps are scheduled to run daily for incremental load.

Comment: @JamesZ - Also the other reason why we wanted to use Azure function is we need to create Vnet and enable vnet peering to establish connection with client databases due to security concerns. So, can you please also suggest if we use Azure Data factory, can we implement vnet peering for the same?

Comment: I've usually done initial loads using sqlldr. Doesn't oracle need to be in a VM in Azure and you need a way to log into the server in any case? I'm not any sort of expert on vnet peering, but why wouldn't it work with azure datafactory? People can't really just "suggest" things unless you explain what is the issue you're having with the particular thing / tool. Also, please don't use Indian words like "lakh" here. I already edited your question so that people will understand it.

Answer (score 0):

There is no related limit with records to be updated in database.

Remember not to use `httptrigger` which has `230s` response limit.

For more details about azure function limit you could refer to this [article](https://medium.com/microsoftazure/azure-functions-limiting-throughput-and-scalability-of-a-serverless-app-5b1c381491e3).